# What Is the Index File of my URL's subdirectory

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've got a site I'm working on in WPEngine. The site is WordPress but I have a subdirectory with a landing page. The URL is set up like this:

```
http://www.example.com/landing/
```

In the landing folder there is a file called index.php which should be the file that my browser is going to but when I edit that file, it doesn't update the content on the page. I can go to:

```
http://www.example.com/landing/index.php
```

And see the changes reflected so it makes me think the file is being drawn from somewhere else. There aren't any other files in the folder that would make sense for this though. I've even tried editing other old copies of the index file that are in this directory but none of the changes are reflected.

I suspected that it was perhaps the .htaccess file messing with the URL since it is on a WPEngine server but that wasn't the case. I went into the .htaccess file and deleted all the rewrite info and tried again and it didn't work.

Is there a way to plug a URL into something and have it show you the file name that's being drawn. I know there's a way to do it with PHP $_SERVER variables but obviously I can't get on the page to find this out so I'm stuck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this line in **`/landing/.htaccess` file**:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /landing/
RewriteRule ^$ index.php [L]
```

Comment: That didn't work either unfortunately. For clarification, I've never had more than one .htaccess file on a server. It's ok to have more than one as long as they are in different directories?

Comment: Also, the .htaccess file that exists is in the root, so to test this I added a new .htaccess file into the /landing/ directory and copy and pasted that code which didn't work.

Comment: I suspect some WP plugin (like caching etc) hijacking request when you request `site.com/landing/`

Comment: To test do this. Add same garbage (random) text on top of your `/landing/.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not for `site.com/landing/` request.

Comment: So yes it did generate a 500 error when I put garbage in that file (in /landing/.htaccess). I've tried the DirectoryIndex again but it still didn't do anything. I suspect there's some sort of cache that I can't break. I always refresh with a hard refresh on my browser (Shift-Command-R on Mac) so it's not refreshing from cache but that doesn't do the trick...

Comment: Once my client gives me WordPress access, I'll try to disable plugins and test it that way as well.

Comment: That updated code worked. Thanks! Any idea why that would have had an effect? Just trying to follow up on what exactly was going wrong there, I'm new to some of this...

Comment: Glad it worked, there is some directive in parent OR Apache config that was overriding `DirectoryIndex` setting.